# Spring Boot: Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar` to implement Kafka in Spring Boot application.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081) ~[zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:3.4.6-1569965]
```

Is this issue resolved?
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/12

If not what is the work around?